# Behaviour of PullWait in Go pub sub library?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am currently experimenting with Google Cloud PubSub's [go library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/blob/master/pubsub/pubsub.go) and consulting the documentation at the same time.

My code tests the behaviour of the `PullWait` function which, according to the [documentation](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/pubsub#PullWait) does the following:

> PullWait pulls messages from the subscription. If there are not enough messages left in the subscription queue, it will block until at least n number of messages arrive or timeout occurs, and n could not be larger than 100.

However, my test shows that regardless of the value `n` specified, I always immediately receive `m` messages where m <= n. Am I missing something here?

Excerpt of code used:

```
msgs, err := pubsub.PullWait(subCtx, subscriptionName, 50)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error when trying to pull messages from subscription: %v", err)
} else {
    for _, msg := range msgs {
        str := string(msg.Data)
        log.Printf("Message [msg-id=%s]: '%v'", msg.ID, str)

        if err := pubsub.Ack(ctx, subscriptionName, msg.AckID); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Unable to acknowledge message [ack-id=%s]: %v", msg.AckID, err)
        }
    }
}
```

And at the time queue contained only one message, which was returned to me rightaway:

> 2015/11/04 11:45:15 Message [msg-id=2384294654226]: 'hello world my friend'

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the documentation is incorrect. PullWait makes a call to the underlying [pull method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) with returnImmediately set to false, which means it waits for *at least one message* (but not more than n messages) to be received. I have submitted a request to make the correction.